# I would like to create a counter that would increase +1 everytime when the user opens up the userform

Tags: excel, vba, unique

[[image: userform [1]]

Can I have the textbox to display a number that would auto increase + 1 everytime a user opens up the userform?

Comment: Just define global variable and use it on form initialization event.

Comment: can u giv an example ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to define a global variable that counts openinng of a form. I assume that you call `UserForm.Show` somewhere in your code, so I would define method to hanle "opening logic".

I would do it like that:

```
' Global variable
Private counter As Long

' Change calls of UserForm.Show to this method
Sub ShowUserForm()
    ' Increment counter
    counter = counter + 1
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = counter
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted, but one remark maybe: The variable is lost upon closing/opening the workbook. Another way to really make sure the number increases each time is to assign the value to a cell. However, OP might want to restart the count in any such case =)

Comment: @JvdV Indeed, you're right, I rather wanted way to tackle the problem and let OP find the best way - other way would be to try with global variable on a form, but as soon as form closes it will be lost. Well, it can be lost in so many ways, that only writing to cell is easy way to solve it. More elegant ways would require additional classes for handilng user form.